# jquery parse json multidimensional

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

i have a json array like this:

```
    {
    "etablissement": {
        "siege_social": true,
        "siret": "41816609600051",
        "naf": "6202A",
        "libelle_naf": "Conseil en systèmes et logiciels informatiques",
        "etat_administratif_etablissement": {
            "value": "Actif",
            "date_mise_a_jour": 1108594800
        },
        "adresse": {
            "l1": "OCTO-TECHNOLOGY",
            "l2": "50 AV DES CHAMPS ELYSEES",
            "l3": "75008 PARIS 8",
            "l4": null,
            "l5": null,
            "numero_voie": "50",
            "type_voie": "AV",
            "nom_voie": "DES CHAMPS ELYSEES",
            "complement_adresse": null,
            "code_postal": "75008",
            "localite": "PARIS 8",
            "code_insee_localite": "75108"
        }
    },
    "gateway_error": false
}
```

I want to use jquery to be able  to return the values of each of the array values, but im not sure as to how to get access to them.

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access any key in the JSON just use `'.' (dot)`. Say, to access "OCTO-TECHNOLOGY" use this `obj.etablissement.adresse.l1`

If you store JSON data in a object 'obj'.

```
var obj={"etablissement": {..........}..}
```

You can do it like this:

```
for (var key in obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    alert(key + " -> " + JSON.stringify(obj[key]));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See [this documentation page](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/) about json parsing.

After parsing, you have a normal javascript object. In your case, an example of parsing would be something like that.

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( yourJSONArray);
console.log(obj.etablissement.siret);
```